# Record video from iPhone to Mac (Camera, not Screen)

Tags: iphone-app, camera

I'm planning to start some sort of Vlog. The problem is, the only good camera I own is the one built in in my iPhone (6S).
Next problem: iPhone peasants have limited storage and unfortunately it's not expandable like an Android master race.

I was thinking that somehow somewhere, there should be a software, where you can record a video on your iPhone and stream it (wirelessly or via USB) directly to your Mac and save it there. Would be awesome.
Or maybe a software which emulates the iPhone as a webcam or something.

Googling only results in people trying to explain to me how to record the screen of my iPhone, which is not the thing I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest iCam App.

```
[https://itunes.apple.com/app/id296273730][1]
```

iCam has a special feature of recording and playing back the motion events. You can also receive the notifications when the iCam detects anything. Although, the application is for iPhone but the sources can be accessed on the windows PC too. And the camera quality is amazing, which is the most important aspect to consider. this is 4.99$ on iTunes, but worth every penny.

More apps are available for 1.99$ but those dont have these many features.

```
https://www.igeeksblog.com/iphone-apps-to-use-iphone-as-webcam/
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Haven't tried it yet, though.

Instant Webcam by PhobosLab
https://appsto.re/de/Q9dXO.i